# How to pass a type to the method/function call?

Tags: c#, generics

I want to make this code shorter, via passing the type as a parameter to `targetUnitOfWork.Query`.

There are two types `SomeListItem` and `SomeList`. And depending on the actual type I have to call either `Query<SomeListItem>` or `Query<SomeList>` as it is shown below.

```
    Type typeName = targetClassInfo.ClassType;
    if (typeName.Equals(typeof(SomeListItem)))
    {
        target = targetUnitOfWork
            .Query<SomeListITem>()
            .Where(i => i.Name.Equals(otherObj.Name)).Where(j => j.SortKey == otherObj.SortKey);
    }
    else if (typeName.Equals(typeof(SomeList)))
    {
        target = targetUnitOfWork
            .Query<SomeList>()
            .Where(i => i.Name.Equals(otherObj.Name)).Where(j => j.SortKey == otherObj.SortKey);
    }
    else
    {
        target = targetClassInfo.CreateNewObject(targetUnitOfWork);
    }
```

How can I solve this task?

Comment: This is a bit unclear

Comment: Does what you're doing not work? Why do you want to make it shorter?

Comment: While it might be a wrong design decision, isn't your example a working one?

Comment: @MarcoSalerno what exactly is not clear in my question?

Comment: @IsaacHildebrandt this code works, I just want to refactor it to make it shorter.

Comment: If the type `targetClassInfo.ClassType` were a type parameter to a generic method that contains this code, you could condense the first two branches.

Comment: I don't really know c# well, but can you not just have it be something like targetUnitOfWork.Query<targetClassInfo.ClassType>()?

Comment: @RoyalBg this code works properly, I just wanted to get rid of this ugly if and pass the type to the Query call. Is it even possible?

Comment: This is fine, it doesn't need to be shorter. I'm almost positive that if you try to make it shorter, you'll end up making it much, much longer and less clear. Leave it.

Comment: @DanRaps thank you for suggestion, but this way won't work in C#.

Comment: No, this is not how generics are passed. The need to be recognized by the compiler at the time of passing, since all the code then will use some static typing. The only way to make this dynamic, is to use `Reflection` with `ParametizedType`, but then you will receive `Object` and now direct method calls will be allowed, so you will need to execute the methods with `Reflection`'s `Invoke` too.

Comment: @NoviceStudent If we knew what types might be involved, and how they relate (do `SomeListItem` and `SomeList` have any common base class other than Object?), this would be a much better question. Then I could tell you whether Royal Bg's "only" is accurate.

Comment: @IsaacHildebrandt thank you, I am just curious. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: If this satisfies you, I will write an answer with an example.

Comment: @EdPlunkett No, these classes are not related to each other.

Comment: @RoyalBg I am curious, how can I make this code shorter, If you post a response with a hint that works, I will accept it. Thank you.

Comment: @NoviceStudent Is it within your power to make them related? If they're not related, how do you use a query that might return either one? I wonder if this might not be the tip of a design iceberg.

Comment: @EdPlunkett if I move `targetClassInfo.ClassType` to a generic type parameter to a method, I will get the same ugly `if` structure but on a higher level of code.

Comment: @EdPlunkett unfortunately I have no power to change these classes.

Comment: I will try to make a minimum working example with a test generic class

Comment: @RoyalBg thank you

Comment: I made a method getting the desired object with desired class from a list containing different classes objects, check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Preface

We will not cover in this answer the **design decision** made by the authors of the code. It's only worth to say that this kind of **heterogeneous generics** should be left to **pattern matching** mechanism instead of polymorphic one.

### Motivation

Either way, there are plenty of cases where you want to **dynamically put generic types and invoke methods in the chain**. It's mostly done in projects serving **libraries and frameworks** for later usage, where parameters are inherited from the user input, or they come lately to the project as an extension by the developers.

### Reflection

Luckily, .NET Framework (and Core as well, the code bellow is .NET Framework) provides a rich `Reflection` library where you can do your metaprogramming model.

The `Reflection` library provides a way to introspect the program, compromising the static typization in favor of dynamic one e.g. to find a method by its name, because it comes from the user input. It's not its sole purpose, but we will use it this way.

### Action in code

In our scenario, we need to call the `Query<T>` method with arbitrary `<T>` which comes from the user input. So let's define a function that will serve this functionality. We will call it `Test`:

```
static void Test(Type type, TestGenerics testGenerics, String otherObjectName)
```

It receives the `System.Type`, an object in our case `TestGenerics` and a `String` to test the `name` property as in the question.

Our `TestGenerics` object is a fake class that mimics the question's semantics:

```
class TestGenerics
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return Enumerable.Repeat(new T(), 10);
    }
}
```

First of all, we need to find the `Query` method by name. Since it's the one and only method named this way (no overloads) we can safely use `FirstOrDefault`:

```
Object enumerable = testGenerics.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Query")
```

But we cannot invoke it directly, as it accepts not only arguments, but generic parameters as well. We can provide them, by providing `Type` to `MakeGenericMethod(Type)` reflection's method:

```
.MakeGenericMethod(type)
```

And then we are ready to `Invoke` it without arguments (as it does not accept any), but we need to specify the object it will be invoked from (in our case `testGenerics`):

```
.Invoke(testGenerics, null);
```

Cool so far, there are the dragons to come here, because we need now to build the `i => i.name == otherObjectName` lambda. The `Where` method from `IEnumerable<T>` extensions (in fact, it's a static method in System.Linq.Enumerable) receives a `Func<T, R>` instead of `Predicate<T>`, so we need to build one:

```
Type predicateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(type, typeof(bool));
```

This builds `Func<,>` e.g. a `Func` type with two generic parameters. The first is the type passed, and the second is boolean to mimic a predicate by function.

Now we need to build the lambdas left side by making a parameter of the given type:

```
ParameterExpression predParam = Expression.Parameter(type, "i");
```

And getting the field `name` from it them:

```
Expression left = Expression.Field(predParam, type.GetField("name"));
```

And the right side of the expressions is the name we will compare it with:

```
Expression right = Expression.Constant(otherObjectName, typeof(string));
```

Building the whole lambda is the next step. From the predicate type (`Func<T, R>`, the equality expression and the predicate param "i"):

```
LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(predicateType, Expression.Equal(left, right), predParam);
```

Now we need to find the `Where` method. It's in the class containing all the extension methods and not in the `IEnumerable` interface:

```
IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methodsEnumerable = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
MethodInfo where = methodsEnumerable.Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2).FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Where");
```

But this is a generic method, receiving the type from the input, so we need to do this as well:

```
MethodInfo genericWhere = where.MakeGenericMethod(type);
```

Since it is a static method, the object must be passed as an argument (as for the semantics of an extension method). The first argument in the object array is the extension interface (`IEnumerable` e.g. the return type of `Query`) and the second argument is the above lambda - compiled:

```
Object response = genericWhere.Invoke(enumerable, new[] {enumerable, lambda.Compile()});
```

And here we will stop with the example. You will need to tweak it for your case and add the other method calls. It's very verbose and ugly as well, but will work for any kind of objects containing the `name` field. In bigger scenarios, if you don't couple to a certain field hardcoded, it will work for wide variety of inputs. The same way how frameworks works with our code.

The full example you can find below:

```
class TypeOne
{
    public string name;
}

class TypeTwo
{
    public string name;
}


internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test(typeof(TypeOne), new TestGenerics(), "John");
        Test(typeof(TypeTwo), new TestGenerics(), "Smith");
    }

    static void Test(Type type, TestGenerics testGenerics, String otherObjectName)
    {
        Object enumerable = testGenerics.GetType().GetMethods().FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Query")
            .MakeGenericMethod(type)
            .Invoke(testGenerics, null);
        Type predicateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(type, typeof(bool));
        ParameterExpression predParam = Expression.Parameter(type, "i");
        Expression left = Expression.Field(predParam, type.GetField("name"));
        Expression right = Expression.Constant(otherObjectName, typeof(string));
        LambdaExpression lambda = Expression.Lambda(predicateType, Expression.Equal(left, right), predParam);
        IEnumerable<MethodInfo> methodsEnumerable = typeof(System.Linq.Enumerable)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        MethodInfo where = methodsEnumerable.Where(m => m.GetParameters().Length == 2).FirstOrDefault(m => m.Name == "Where");
        MethodInfo genericWhere = where.MakeGenericMethod(type);
        Object response = genericWhere.Invoke(enumerable, new[] {enumerable, lambda.Compile()});
        Console.WriteLine(response);
    }
}

class TestGenerics
{
    public IEnumerable<T> Query<T>() where T : new()
    {
        return Enumerable.Repeat(new T(), 10);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use generic method like this:

```
    private void SomeMethod<T>()
    {
        target = targetUnitOfWork
            .Query<T>()
            .Where(i => i.Name.Equals(otherObj.Name)).Where(j => j.SortKey == otherObj.SortKey);
    }
```

Then you can call `SomeMethod<SomeList>()` or `SomeMethod<SomeListItem>()`

Comment: still you need to if

Comment: thank you, having a method with generic type just moves this if construction to the higher level, is not it? I need to check the type an make a call, either SomeMethod<SomeList>(true) or SomeMethod<SomeListItem>(true). Is not it?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you want to do, right?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<object> listOfObjects = new List<object>() { new Item(), new Dog(), new Cat(), new Human() };
        Dog martin = GetFirstOrDefault<Dog>(listOfObjects);
    }

    static T GetFirstOrDefault<T>(List<object> listOfObjects)
    {
        return (T)listOfObjects.Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(T)).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}

class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
}

class Dog
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Cat
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

class Human
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birth { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you. You are applying type parameter to a list in `where` clause, but I wanted to apply type parameter to the method call, `targetUnitOfWork.Query<....>`.

Comment: Maybe i don't get your ovjective

Comment: I appreciate your help, Marco. There is a call to the method `Query` that uses a type. I.e `Query<SomeList>` or `Query<SomeListItem>`. I just curious how can I avoid `if` construction and pass `SomeList` or `SomeListItem` types as parameters to the `Query` call. As you can see from my other comments to answers, making a parametrized method just moves this `if` construction to the higher lever, but not eliminates it.

Comment: But using the if is wrong, you have to treat it as T so you can use every class

Answer (score 1):

Things are only going to get complicated (messy?) from here on.

Ok, so first two queries are same. So, you might go for a generic method. Something of this sort:

```
    public IEnumerable<T> GetListTarget<T>(bool applyWhere) // You will need to add an constraint here that is applicable to both classes. Only then compiler will be able to understand the properties you are using in the where method
    {
        if (applyWhere)
        {
            return targetUnitOfWork
                 .Query<T>()
                 .Where(i => i.Name.Equals(otherObj.Name)).Where(j => j.SortKey == otherObj.SortKey);
        }
        else
        {
            return targetClassInfo.CreateNewObject(targetUnitOfWork);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thank you, having a method with generic type just moves this if construction to the higher level, is not it? I need to check the type an make a call, either `GetListTarget<SomeList>(true)` or `GetListTarget<SomeListItem>(true)`. Is not it?

Comment: Yes the calls will look like that. You do not need to check the types anymore. The flag only tells whether to apply where clause or not. Both classes MUST have a common base class or an interface so compiler can identify the properties in where method. Also, this is going to get messy if there are more types. May be you need to take a look at some of the builder patterns

Comment: Also, I am assuming whether you apply where or not, the return type is an enumerable. If that is not the case, remove the flag and split this into 2 methods.

Comment: even I split this method to 2 methods, I will need to have an if construction on a higher level, to check what type should be passed to the `GetListTarget` method. In other words I will need to use an if to determine should I call `GetListTarget<SomeList>` or call `GetListTarget<SomeListItem>`.

Comment: Yes. If you are really after removing type checks, it will involve redesigning. I don't know why do you have targetClassInfo object, why do you even have this kind of set up. There are so many missing pieces for people here that I doubt you someone will be able to help you get rid of the type checks.